# Rollup.js - have PostCSS process whole bundle.css instead of individual files from rollup-plugin-svelte

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, postcss, rollupjs

I've tried several guides and many configurations, but can't get my rollup, postcss, and svelte bundle process to work quite right.

Right now the svelte plugin is extracting the css from my .svelte files and emitting it to the posctcss plugin, but it's doing it one file at a time instead of the entire bundle.  This makes it so some functions in the purgecss and nanocss postcss plugins don't completely work because they need the entire bundle to do things like remove duplicate/redundant/unused css rules.

```js
// rollup.config.js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte'
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve'
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs'
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
import rollup_start_dev from './rollup_start_dev'
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH

export default {
    input: 'src/main.js',
    output: {
        sourcemap: true,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        file: 'public/bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            dev: !production,
            emitCss: true,
        }),
        postcss({
            extract: true,
            sourceMap: true,
        }),
        builtins(),
        resolve({
            browser: true,
            dedupe: importee =>
                importee === 'svelte' || importee.startsWith('svelte/'),
        }),
        commonjs(),
        !production && rollup_start_dev,
        !production && livereload('public'),
        production && terser(),
    ],
    watch: {
        clearScreen: false,
    },
}
```

```js
// postcss.config.js
const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH
const purgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss')


module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        require('postcss-import')(),
        require('tailwindcss'),
        require('autoprefixer'),
        production &&
            purgecss({
                content: ['./src/**/*.svelte', './src/**/*.html', './public/**/*.html'],
                css: ['./src/**/*.css'],
                whitelistPatterns: [/svelte-/],
                defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
            }),
        production &&
            require('cssnano')({
                preset: 'default',
            }),
    ],
}
```

How can I have rollup pass the entire bundle.css to postcss instead of one "file" at a time?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, preprocess goes file by file, so I had to actually include all my mixins and vars in every file, which is absolutely not a good solution.

So for me the first solution was to remove postcss from sveltePreprocess, not emit the css file and to use postcss on the css bundle, that you get in the css function from svelte.

You can then or (1) use postcss directly in the css function of svelte, and then emit the resulting css file in your dist directory, or (2) you can emit this file in a CSS directory, and have `postcss-cli` watch this directory and bundle everything

## Solution 1

```js
// rollup.config.js

// rollup.config.js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

import postcss from 'postcss';
import postcssConfig from './postcss.config.js';
const postcssPlugins = postcssConfig({});
const postcssProcessor = postcss(postcssPlugins);

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'public/bundle.js',
    format: 'iife',
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      emitCss: false,
      css: async (css) => {
        const result = await postcssProcessor.process(css.code);
        css.code = result.css;
        css.write('public/bundle.css');
      },
    }),
    resolve(),
  ],
};
```

and my postcss.config.js which returns a function that return an array of plugins:

```js
export default (options) => {
  const plugins = [
    require('postcss-preset-env')()
  ];

  if (options.isProd) {
    plugins.push(require('cssnano')({ autoprefixer: false }));
  }

  return plugins;
};
```

## Solution 2

```js
// rollup.config.js
import svelte from 'rollup-plugin-svelte';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    file: 'public/bundle.js',
    format: 'iife',
  },
  plugins: [
    svelte({
      emitCss: false,
      css: async (css) => {
        css.write('css/svelte-bundle.css');
      },
    }),
    resolve(),
  ],
};
```

```js
// package.json
{
  //...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel js:watch css:watch",
    "js:watch": "rollup -c -w",
    "css:watch": "postcss css/app.css --dir dist/ --watch",
  },
}
```

```css
/* css/app.css */
@import 'vars.css';
@import 'mixins.css';

/* all other code ... */

/* and svelte-bundle, which will trigger a bundling with postcss everytime it is emitted */
@import 'svelte-bundle.css';
```

## Conclusion

All in all, I don't like this methods, for exemple because I can't use nesting, as svelte throws an error if the css is not valid.

I would prefer being able to use `rollup-plugin-postcss` after `rollup-plugin-svelte`, with `emitCss` set to false and the possibility to use rollup's `this.emitFile` in svelte css function, because since once the bundled file is emitted, we should be able to process it.

It seems there are some issues talking about using emitfile, let's hope it will happen sooner than later https://github.com/sveltejs/rollup-plugin-svelte/issues/71

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure, but when i compare your setup with mine the most striking difference is that i have:

```
css: css => {
                css.write('public/build/bundle.css');
            }
```

in the svelte options additionally.

My whole svelte option looks like this:

```
svelte({
    preprocess: sveltePreprocess({ postcss: true }),
    dev: !production,
    css: css => {
        css.write('public/build/bundle.css');
    }
})
```

Note, i'm using `sveltePreprocess` which would make your `postcss` superfluous, but i don't think that is causing your issue.